# Rendering issues with ExtJS and Angular

Tags: visualforce, javascript, angularjs, extjs

I'm building a page that does some heavy processing in a CSV file, so I opted for AngularJS to build it.  I've noticed, however, that there is a library that is used by Salesforce that is lagging the page rendering a lot.

[image: ExtJS is slow]

[image: ExtJS is slow as hell]

Is it possible to disable ExtJS on a VF page? I've tried setting `showHeader`, `standardStylesheets`, `sidebar` and `applyHtmlTag` to `false` and the script still loads!

Every time I make a Remote Action call within Angular, the page seems to lag for a few seconds, and then normalize when the request finishes and the page is rerendered by the browser.

Comment: Have you tried `showHeader="false"`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried both `showHeader` and `sidebar` set to `false`, and the script still loads with it.

Comment: What about stripping it all the way down? Like `standardStylesheets`, `applyHtmlTag`, and so on? Also, probably ought to [edit] your post to include this sort of information.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this with Firefox, and it worked just fine. Maybe its an issue related to Chrome/Chromium. Should I delete this question, or answer it?

Comment: I'm always on the side of answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who also noticed that the page becomes slow when using Visualforce Remoting, please check if you are using Chrome. I've tested the same page, doing the same thing, on Firefox, and it was a smooth experience.

This lagging issue might be related to Chrome, after all.